# How to create multiple columns in UITableView i.e CustomCellView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7

I am just starting iOS development. I am trying to display a multiple columns in UItableview from NSArray? So please help me anyone? I have created one column but i don,t know how to create another column?

I have done the following.

```
// This is my code 

- (NSArray *)numbers
{

    NSArray *col1 = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];
    return col1;

}
- (NSArray *)numberCodes
{

    NSArray *col2 = @[@"Roy", @"Ankit", @"Jhon", @"Kem", @"Pawan"];
    return col2;

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.numbers.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];



    //cell.textLabel.text = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.numberCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show your tried code, it is easy to solve

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `UITableView` isn't a table in tha sense of rows and coloums; by itself, it has only one 'coloumn'.

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

on your `viewController.h` create the one Global Array like

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;
```

on your `ViewController.m` allocate the memory of that array like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten",nil];

}
```

on that `tableview Datasource` method do like

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

return [tableData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {

 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"XXXX";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 }

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

 }
```

for sample see [this](http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

**1. You may create costume cell like having multiple fields/column in table.** 
**2. Place multiple table view, one for each column. Use auto-layout for better look.**